# trying to get property of non-object - Laravel?

Tags: php, multithreading, laravel

I'm doing a blog to learn how to use laravel. The blog is mostly finished but I still found some mistakes in my code. Most of them are solved but there is still one error I can't fix.

It's about the 'my thread' of the user. If the user did a new account, he also get a 'my thread' page. If he's klicking on the page, he will get a view with all his threads. My problem now is, that if he don't have any threads, he will get a:

trying to get property of non-object exception. Of course I don't want him to see this.

So this is the function in my controller to his 'my thread' page:

```
public function startpage($id)
    {
//        $userthreads = Thread::query()->where('user_id', $id)->get();
//        return $userthreads;
        try {
            return view('test.startpage', [
                'userthreads' => Thread::query()->where('user_id', $id)->get(),
                'user' => User::query()->findOrFail($id)
            ]);
        } catch (ModelNotFoundException $e) {
            return view('test.notfound');
        }
    }
```

with the first two ( uncommented ) lines, I checked if there was something in the array. I just got

`'[]'`

as an output. That means the array is empty. I returned the $userthreads variable to the view and on my view I did this to avoid the problem:

```
            @if(empty($userthreads))
                <a href="{{ action('Test\\TestController@add') }}">Add Thread </a>
            @else
            @foreach($userthreads as $uthread)
                    <ul>
                        <a href="{{ action('Test\\TestController@show', [$uthread->id]) }}">{{$uthread->thread}}</a>
                    </ul>
            @endforeach
            @endif
```

This haven't worked for me and I can't see why. Maybe someone of you can help me there.

Thanks for any help!

Current code of Alexey Mezenin answers:

```
public function startpage($id)
    {
        try {
            $arr = [];
            $arr['userthreads'] = Thread::where('user_id', $id)->get();
            $arr['user'] = User::findOrFail($id);

            return view('test.startpage', $arr);

        } catch (ModelNotFoundException $e) {
            return view('test.notfound');
        }
    }
```

HTML:

```
@if(count($userthreads) > 0)
            <a href="{{ action('Test\\TestController@add') }}">Thread hinzufügen</a>
            @else
            @foreach($userthreads as $uthread)
                    <ul>
                        <a href="{{ action('Test\\TestController@show', [$uthread->id]) }}">{{$uthread->thread}}</a>
                    </ul>
            @endforeach
            @endif
```

Error :

```
Trying to get property of non-object (View: /var/www/laravel/logs/resources/views/test/startpage.blade.php)
```

Comment: have you tried by changing if condition @if(isset($userthreads)) instead empty or by count @if(count($userthreads) > 0)

Comment: I tried both but nothing of them seems to help. Both tries gave me the same error message..

Comment: change(Swap) content of if bloack with else and else block with if.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, we discussed it in chat and found a problem:

```
@if(Auth::user()->id == $userthreads->first()->user_id)
```

Comment: I tried the cound method and the catch logic but both haven't worked :/

Comment: and the controller function can't be the problem :/ if the user have a thread it all works.. thats why I don't think there is a mistake

Comment: Why are you so sure? Look at your error, I think the error is in `op()` action.

Comment: mhh.. well I removed the ->query() parts but this haven't worked either

Comment: You removed it from my code or yours? Same error or different?

Comment: I removed ->query() from my contoller function

Comment: Try my code. If it will fail, please update your post with full error report.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105798/discussion-between-itzme488-and-alexey-mezenin).

Answer (score 0):

Error is in your startpage.blade.php here

```
@if( Auth::user()->id == $userthreads->first()->user_id)
```

And change it like below

```
@if( isset($userthreads) && count($userthreads) > 0 && Auth::user()->id == $userthreads->first()->user_id)
```

that's it

```
@if(isset($userthreads) && count($userthreads) > 0)

  @foreach($userthreads as $uthread)
   <ul>
      <a href="{{ action('Test\\TestController@show', [$uthread->id]) }}">{{$uthread->thread}}</a>
   </ul>
  @endforeach

@else
  <a href="{{ action('Test\\TestController@add') }}">Thread hinzufügen</a>
@endif
```

Answer (score 0):

@ItzMe488
I think replacing the following code :

`@if( Auth::user()->id == $userthreads->first()->user_id)`

with

`@if( Auth::user()->id == $user->first()->user_id)`

should work without any errors and bugs.

**Explanation:**

In our chat @AlexeyMezenin found out that the error is because `$userthreads` is empty and `$userthreads->first()` errors out because of that. I think since you are passing `$user` also into the template, using that we can authenticate for the current user and this should prevent user B from creating threads in User A's page.